# SQL : create view over heterogeneous tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Image you have a database, where there is a certain number of tables for every type the table's belong to.

What i mean is that if you have a type "Person" with the "ipotetic" rows Name, Surname, Phone and Address; this will involve in a certain number of table (eg 3) as show below :

Table `Person_1` :

```
 Name      Surname
 =================
 Jhon      Doe
 Jhon      Smith
```

Table `Person_2` :

```
 Name      Surname      Phone
 =============================
 Alan      Ford         555 2536
```

Table `Person_3` :

```
 Name      Surname      Phone      Address
 =========================================
 Marty     McFly        555 2434   something
```

What I would obtain is a single view with all of the previous record

`View` :

```
 Name      Surname      Phone      Address
 =========================================
 Marty     McFly        555 2434   something
 Jhon      Doe
 Alan      Ford         555 2536
 Jhon      Smith
 Alan      Ford         555 2536
```

Is this possible ?

My problem is also that there is no guarantee on the Person table (so tomorrow an user could add new Person_4 with another row).

I have no problem to check each Persons table structure and declare appropriate view with the sum of  all column (programmatically by my program), but i do not know syntax to pack each table row into that view.

(I will not use stored procedure, each operations is done by my program that need to compose the correct sql script and send it to database)

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: Your hypothetical design is completely broken. Why do you have 3 different tables?

Comment: @Mat Obviously incompetence as in not knowing how SQL works. THAT SAID - this is why he hs asking and thus we should help him. But yeah, the main problem is fixing the bad code to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your database design is flawed. I say this because you have a new table for every new piece of data. 
Data should be organized into tables and every new piece of data should make up a row within that table.

The view you have said you want to create is in fact what your `persons` table should look like.

I recommend you start by looking at what data you want to store, then create a table reflecting that. For example, in your example you look at four pieces of data: 
Name, Surname, Phone and address.

Let’s put that all into one table:

```
| Person_ID   | First_Name | Last_Name | Phone_Number | Address |
```

As you will have noticed, I have also added an ‘ID’ column. ID columns are used to `Join` pieces of data together, across tables. They give an identity to each row in your table that you can then use to correspond to another column in another table of related data. I won’t go into joins as that isn't in your question, but you can find out more about them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Let’s write a script to create such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONS 
(
   [PERSON_ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
   [First_Name] varchar (20),
   [Last_Name] varchar(20),
   [Phone_Number] int,
   [Address] varchar (100)
)
```

Now that we have a table, we need to add data.

Instead of creating a new table, we need to add another row to the already existing table.
You can do that by using the ‘[Insert](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)’ keyword.

An example script would be as follows:

```
INSERT INTO PERSONS ([First_Name], [Last_Name], [Phone_Number], [Address])
VALUES ('Kid', 'Code', 0123456789, '123 False Street, Springfield'),
       ('Mike', 'Myers', 0123456789, '124 False Street, Springfield')
```

Then if you run `SELECT * FROM Persons` you should get: (only difference being your ID for Mike will be 2)

[image: Select Results]

Comment: i had supposed that my design is not correct solution (to complex), but my problem is that i need to handle some kind of custom tags over a known object. So even if i can model that known object and i can join it with other tables, i have no idea about how represent those auxiliary informations avoiding giant precompiled tables (eg : [ext_id,str_0,..,strn,int_0,..,int_n]) or huge column to row tables ( eg : [ext_id,str,int] ) where each entry is an additional cell of some other table's row. So my idea was to dynamically replicate each table according to custom tags.

Comment: What are these custom tags? What tables do you want to join? What do you mean by precompiled tables? -Are you referring to prepared statements? Please expand your question so I can expand my answer.

Comment: The custom tags are attributes that a runtime users add to main object (usually strings, numbers and dates). With term precompiled tablet i mean build a tablet with houndred of colums where only few are used for ma in object, and the other are placed but used only if necessary for some custom tag.

Comment: With ColToRow table i mean a key value table where certain number of row represent some tags referenced (by key) to the main object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108262/where-all-is-not-null

Have you had a look at the above?

Comment: Just to throw something into to the mix here, maybe relational storage isn't the way to go here. I would consider looking into entity based storage such as MongoDB, DynamoDB, etc. It might be better suited for your scenario because it makes it more flexible when dealing with a large number of unknown attributes.

Comment: @Ola MongoDB was exactly what i would liked to use, unfortunately i have some constraint so i can only use SQL Server 2012.
If i not find any other better ideas (in spite of all) i suppose i will use a giant precompiled table (instead of my original idea that appear to be impraticable)

Comment: @Skary look into using Sparse Columns for your app when designing your tables in SQL 2012, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @Ola really interesting, now i am trying to undestand if it is possibile alter existing table to add a new sparse column or if it's too expensive (expecially when there are a lot of rows).
Thanks again for the article.