# SQL Select ONLY Non-Empty Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 25 columns in a SQL Server 2008 table and I ONLY AND ONLY need to select the cells which are not empty. So far I have tried the `Where` condition like:

```
Select * 
from TableNmae 
where ColumnA is not like '% %' 
  and  ColumnB is not like '% %' ,etc...
```

And I also tried the `Union` and `Union All` for all the columns but non of them returns only the non-empty cells for a given condition.

Comment: Empty? Do you mean NULL, or with zero length values? You can only select defined rows, so what do you want if one value empty?

Comment: They are of type nvarchar so I mean Not Null. I just need to select Only and Only not null cells from a row.

Comment: Is not null instead of like

Comment: So  zero length means "empty"?

Comment: you don't select "cells" in sql - you select columns and return rows. Your requirement doesn't really make sense, unless you mean you want to filter the query to only return rows that contain non-empty-cells?

Comment: Give example results. Closing for now.

Comment: this is exactly my question "returning only the non empty columns within a row using one select statement, that can't be done." Can I do it with a loop and insert the result into a temp table?

Comment: People don't understand what you want. That's why nobody answers although this is probably an easy question. Why haven't you given sample results yet as I requested? Why didn't you respond to my comment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108262/where-all-is-not-null/47317997#47317997

Might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write this like the following in order to use indexes if any exists:

```
Select * 
From TableName 
Where ColumnA Is Not NULL And ColumnA <> '' 
  And ColumnB Is Not NULL And ColumnB <> ''
.......
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to be row-based, you could union together a bunch of individual column evaluations:

```
SELECT 'ColumnA' AS ColumnName, ColumnA AS ColumnValue
FROM TableName
WHERE NOT ColumnA IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'ColumnB' AS ColumnName, ColumnB AS ColumnValue
FROM TableName
WHERE NOT ColumnB IS NULL

UNION ALL

-- etc....
```

Some of the other answers also show more flexible ways of using IsNull to help weed out null vs. empty values...would be good to add that in here as well. You might also want to select key fields from the table to allow you to identify source rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from TableNmae 
where ColumnA is not null
and  ColumnB is not null ...
```

Comment: Seriously? The question asks to "select cells that are not empty", and an answer that does just that is downvoted?

Comment: Balanced it for you with a +1, _but_ strictly speaking you are not checking for "not empty", you're checking for "not null". The OP was not very clear though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from TableNmae 
where isnull(ColumnA,'') != ''
   and  isnull(ColumnB, '') != ''
```

Unless it's a numerical datatype you'll have to set isnull to 0 or convert/cast to varchar datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using isnull like,

`Select * 
from TableNmae 
where IsNull(ColumnA, '') <> ''
  and IsNull(ColumnA, '') <> ''...`

This should address isnull and empty as well.  This will return rows that doesn't have all empty columns.
If you question is about returning only the non empty columns within a row using one select statement, that can't be done.

Comment: this is exactly my question "returning only the non empty columns within a row using one select statement, that can't be done." Can I do it with a loop and insert the result into a temp table?

Comment: Yes and No, it depends on how you want your output, Do you want all columns as one single column in output. What if more than one columns has data in a row.