# SQL Server - Filter only rows which have values in all columns

Tags: filter, sql-server-2012

How do I filter rows those have values in all columns (i.e exclude the row if they have a missing value/null in any of the columns)

Say:

```
id  name   age    height
------------------------
1   abc     19    NULL
2   fds     34    2.3
3   grt    NULL   NULL
```

Output should be only row2. How do I do this?

Comment: `WHERE id IS NOT NULL and name IS NOT NULL and age IS NOT NULL and height IS NOT NULL`

Comment: thanks and forgot to mention this,  What if I have 30+ columns in the table. I know your query will work, is there a better way to do it for all columns instead of writing it with 'AND and IS NOT NULL'

Comment: No, there's no "magic shortcut" to do this - if you want to make sure you have values in **all** columns, you must use `(column) IS NOT NULL` for each of them

Comment: when I have to do something like this w/ a lot of columns, I paste the column names into Excel - say column A - put the recurring value in column B (IS NOT NULL), then in column C formula "and "&A1&" "&$B$1...autofill down, copy that back into SQL

Comment: @marc_s it's beyond me to comment on it's efficacy, but do you have any opinion on Anax's answer here - it's mysql though, but maybe there's an equivalent... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108262/where-all-is-not-null

Comment: yeah tats one way. Guess you also can use Ctrl+H smartly to replace ',<column>' after you select top 1000 rows from SQL server inbuilt function. But, I was thinking if there was some other way of joining with system tables or information_schema tables to do it dynamically.